# Does this code in htaccess indicate that maybe it has been hacked?

Tags: .htaccess, server

I have very little knowledge about servers and especially about htaccess.
I found this code in an htaccess file, do you think it was hacked?

```
<FilesMatch ".(py|exe|php)$">
 Order allow,deny
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "^(about.php|radio.php|index.php|content.php|lock360.php|admin.php|wp-login.php)$">
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This looks a bit amateurish as a setup, but I do not see anything that hints on modifications I would immediately associate with someone from the outside trying to redirect traffic or anything. Though I obviously don't know the content of those php files tried to whitelist here.